# Best way to declare a constant string in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, constants

I have a string: `"The world is a beautiful place to live in."`.

I have two source files and a global header file. I can access the string in two easy ways:-

- Declaring and defining a constant variable as shown: I can use it using `extern`

  `const char *str = "The world is a beautiful place to live in.";`
- Using `#define STR "The world is a beautiful place to live in."`

Out of the above two options, which one is preferred in C?

Comment: Besides the definition of the "variable" `str` being wrong, it's *mostly* a matter of personal taste, and how you're supposed to use it.

Comment: Considering one will pollute every translation unit that includes that header with a global variable. The answer is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter (doesn't matter if you only consider of getting a string literal) how you do but in case you want to get the string constant to be traced under debugger you may want to use the `const char*str = ...`

> With macro definition you will get all the problems of macro
>   expansion- the side effects of the expanson, the pollution of the name
>   space, the deviation from debugger help etc